# multiple select with between condition give wrong value

Tags: php

i want to ask about multiple select with between condition.
i have made the code but i have got wrong callback value. in my php function i give two between condition, first between from date_awal and date_akhir and second from kode and kode_mat. but when i'm running the program i got wrong value from the date.
`(example : i want select date 21-08-2017 to 22-08-2017)` when i'm running it i got it wrong value. i just got the data from 21-08-2017 only and the data from 22-08-2017 didn't showing, but when i change the date from `21-08-2017 to 22-08-2017` i can get the data. and something make me confuse i can get right value from between condition from kode1 and kode2. maybe someone can solve that. please help me

this is my php call function

```html
<?php
include("../../Connections/koneksi.php");

$date_awal=$_POST['date_start'];
$date_akhir=$_POST['date_end'];
$kode=$_POST['kode_mat'];
$kode_mat=$_POST['kode_mate'];
$sloc=$_POST['s_loc'];
$s_loc=$_POST['s_loc1'];
$type=$_POST['get_type'];
//Display all data
$rows = array();
$sql = "SELECT * FROM wjm WHERE (date BETWEEN '$date_awal' AND '$date_akhir') AND (kode BETWEEN '$kode' AND '$kode_mat') order by kode asc";
$query = mysqli_query($db,$sql);

while($tmp= mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $rows[] = $tmp;
}

echo json_encode($rows);
```

Comment: **warning** your code is extremely vunlerable to sql injection

Comment: Daniel, you could assume there's all kinds of problems, especially when the entire question is considered, but there's not enough code to know what Rob is doing with those variables before the query. There's also not enough code to know how to answer correctly, so I guess nobody wins.

Comment: @BrianGottier i have edit my code with my all php code

Comment: Try this and see what you get. Do this in database client directly like phpmyadmin or whatever you are using. `SELECT * FROM wjm WHERE date BETWEEN '2017-08-21' AND '2017-08-22'` Note: database saves and compare dates in `yyyy-mm-dd` format not `21-08-2017`

Comment: So as not to be an enabler of vulnerable code, I can't give you an answer, other than to point you to this: http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Comment: @Bsienn i just typo 10-08-2017 the right date is 2017-08-21

Comment: I said just run the query in your sql client and see what you get in return. I think you'll get some idea that way for what is going on.

or just print the sql the code is generating and run that query to see what is going on. Other than this I think no one can help you much with your question here.

Comment: @Bsienn i have run it and i got all data. from that date

Comment: @BrianGottier thanks for this php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php i think i must learn more about this

Answer (score 0):

See, if your columns in db are of type datetime then the date "22-08-2017" is actually "22-08-2017 00:00:00" That is the beginning of the day. Everything during the day is not included..

so to handle it by 2 different ways:

```
1.$sql = "SELECT * FROM wjm WHERE (DATE(date) BETWEEN '$date_awal' AND '$date_akhir') AND (DATE(kode) BETWEEN '$kode' AND '$kode_mat') order by kode asc";

OR 

2. $sql = "SELECT * FROM wjm WHERE date >= '$date_awal' AND date <= '$date_akhir' AND kode >= '$kode' AND kode <= '$kode_mat' order by kode asc";
```